# Batch json strings processing using playframework in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I use API which might either return a single json string, a batch of json strings or the string `PROCESSING_TIMEOUT`, e.g.:

```
{"id":123,"field1":"test1"}
```

or:

```
{"id":123,"field1":"test1"}
{"id":456,"field2":"test2"}
{"id":789,"field3":"test3"}
```

or (in case of asynchronous processing timeout in remote API)

```
PROCESSING_TIMEOUT
```

In the function `getRestContent` I want to be able to correcty process all these possible outputs, including also the timeout errors. In the current version of the function I lack the possibility to process batch json strings. I think that the best option would be that the function returns `List<JsValue>` instead of `JsValue`.
How can I do this modification using `Play Framework`.

```
  def getRestContent(url:String,param:String,paramValue:String): JsValue = {
    var output : JsValue = null
    var httpOutput : String = null
    try {
      val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http(url).timeout(connTimeoutMs = 10000000, readTimeoutMs = 10000000).param(param,paramValue).asString
      httpOutput = response.body
    } catch
    {
      case ex: Exception => {
        println("Failed connection with remote API")
      }
    }

    if (!httpOutput.contains("PROCESSING_TIMEOUT") && httpOutput != null)
    {
      try {
        output = Json.parse(httpOutput)
      }
      catch
        {
          case ex: Exception => {
            println("Failed to process a document")
          }
        }
    }
    else
    {
      println("Asynchronous processing timeout")
    }

    if (output != null)
    {
      return output
    }
    else {
      return new JsObject(Map("empty" -> JsNumber(0)))
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding Play Framework your code is not Scala-flavored in general.
Below is a simple example of how better to approach such task in more Scala-way.
Highlights: use `scala.util.Try` wrapper to normally work with exceptions in a functional way, use pattern matching and monadic `map` and other methods of collections.
I hope the code below is self-explanatory. I mimicked the API. It returns Strings and not JSON but your 3 basic cases are sufficiently emulated: single line, multiple lines and exceptional case.
Try to run the program few times and you will see that all 3 cases are handled correctly:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try, Random}

/**
  * Created by Alex on 3/10/2016.
  */
object Temp {
  case class Item(name:String, value:Int)

  object API{
    def getTimeOutResponse:String = throw new TimeoutException("no luck this time")
    def getSingleLineResponse = "{name: \"Alex\", value: 1}"
    def getMultiLineResponse = "{name: \"Alex\", value: 1}\n{name: \"HackerDuck\", value: 2}"

    def getRandomResponse = (Math.abs(Random.nextInt() % 3)) match{
      case 0 => getTimeOutResponse
      case 1 => getSingleLineResponse
      case 2 => getMultiLineResponse
    }
  }

  def getResults:List[Item]={
    Try(API.getRandomResponse) match{
      case Success(s) =>{
        s.split("\n").toList.map{item =>
          val parts = item.split(", ")
          Item(parts(0).replace("{name: ", "").replace("\"", ""), parts(1).replace("value: ", "").replace("}", "").toInt)
        }
      }
      case Failure(_) =>{
        println("API timeout happened")
        List.empty[Item]
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String])={
    println(getResults)
    println(getResults)
    println(getResults)
  }

}
```

A sample output from my console:

```
API timeout happened
List()
List(Item(Alex,1))
List(Item(Alex,1), Item(HackerDuck,2))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code becomes less cluttered without all these `if` statements and `!=null` and alike. Also you can streamline conversion of your elements sequence to `List` in one place.